# Polymer basic issue

Tags: polymer

Hi I'm trying to execute a basic polymer program. Getting the below exception at step  `var el = new HelloElement();`. Also the element itself is not attached to the page.

Exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at PropertyAccessors (property-accessors.html:119)
    at TemplateStamp (template-stamp.html:119)
    at PropertyEffects (property-effects.html:1075)
    at PolymerElement (element-mixin.html:459)
    at GestureEventListeners (gesture-event-listeners.html:40)
    at LegacyElement (legacy-element-mixin.html:69)
    at PolymerGenerated (class.html:137)
    at (index):18
    at html-imports.js:580
    at html-imports.js:617
```

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"> </script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
</head>
  <body>
      <script>
          HTMLImports.whenReady( function () {
          HelloElement = Polymer.Class({
              is: "hello-element",
              created: function () {
                  this.textContent = "Hello World";
              }
          });
          document.registerElement('hello-element', HelloElement);

          var el = new HelloElement();
          document.querySelector("body").appendChild(el);
      })
      </script>
  </body>
</html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the new class syntax as below:

```
HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
  class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'my-element'; }
    static get properties() {
      return {
        prop: {
          type: String
        }
      }
    }
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.prop = 'my-element'
    }
  }
  customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);

  var el = new MyElement();
  el.textContent = 'my-element';
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(el);
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/vefelacada/edit?html,console,output

See more informations at: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements

=== Edit

If you really want to use Polymer 1.0 syntax, you should probably do something like: (not 100% sure what the error really means)

```
  Polymer({
    is: "hello-element",
  });

  var el = document.createElement("hello-element");
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(el);
  el.textContent = 'my-element';
```

http://jsbin.com/zihayumaqo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Thnx...Are there any good video tutorials for polymer? The ones that I see seem to be outdated

Comment: I guess the polycasts are still a good starting point. There is also the documentation on the polymer website and the polymer slack channel...

Comment: @user3310115 btw, please accept the answer if that solved you issue :)